# Is it possible to add a message bar/ toolbar at the bottom of a titleareadialog?

Tags: java, swt, jface

With my `TitleAreaDialog` is it possible to add a area or a bar across the bottom, below the buttons.  That a message can be displayed to the users, when a operation is taking place.

Here is a example of what I am referring to

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible for JFace `Dialog`s. Depending on what exactly you are doing, you might want to have a look at JFace [`ApplicationWindow`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fwindow%2FApplicationWindow.html). This class has a method `addStatusLine()`. You would have to override the following method:

```
@Override
protected StatusLineManager createStatusLineManager() {
    StatusLineManager statusLineManager = new StatusLineManager();
    statusLineManager.setMessage(null, "YOUR_MESSAGE");
    return statusLineManager;
}
```

You can change the text with:

```
getStatusLineManager().setMessage("YOUR_NEW_MESSAGE");
```

[Here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.rcp.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fwizards%2Fjface%2Fapplicationwindow.html) is an excellent overview of the `ApplicationWindow` class.

Comment: Is a ApplicationWindow as robust as a Dialog?  Things such as buttons and table viewers?  Being I have never used SWT before to create a application, I just assumed that Dialogs was the way to go.

Comment: @jkteater Well, `ApplicationWindow` does not include buttons by default. However, you can add anything you want to it. It may be a little work to convert your current application. If it's worth the effort, depends on how much you need a status line.

Comment: Don't have to have the status line that much.  I just want to make sure that I am correctly setting this application up correctly.  I am afraid that I am going to have memory leaks and issues.  I will probably open a new question and just see if I am using a correct procedures